# AttributeError: 'ModelData' object has no attribute 'design_info'

Tags: python-3.x, anova, statmodels

I am unable to perform annova on a linear regression model. I have attached the simplified code below. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

# define the data
x1 = np.random.rand(100)
x2 = np.random.rand(100)
y = 2*x1 + 3*x2 + np.random.normal(size=100)

# build the model with all independent variables
X = sm.add_constant(np.column_stack((x1, x2)))
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

# perform the F-test
f_value, p_value, _ = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=1)
```

Error screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From `anova_lm` [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm.html#statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm):

> ### Notes
>
> Model statistics are given in the order of args. Models must have been fit
> using the formula api.

You would need to use the [formula API](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.ols.html#statsmodels.formula.api.ols) when defining your model

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.rand(100)
x2 = np.random.rand(100)
y = 2*x1 + 3*x2 + np.random.normal(size=100)
X = sm.add_constant(np.column_stack((x1, x2)))

model = smf.ols("y ~ X", data={"y": y, "X": X}).fit()

print(sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=1))
```

Additionally I'm not sure why you're adding a constant in `X`. In this way your fitted model would end up having two intercepts.
I guess what you were actually trying to achieve was

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

X = np.random.rand(100, 2)
y = 2 * X[:, 0] + 3 * X[:, 1] + np.random.normal(size=100)

model = smf.ols("y ~ X", data={"y": y, "X": X}).fit()

print(model.params)
```